# Umbraco custom EventHandlers, how to set error message

Tags: event-handling, umbraco, umbraco6

First, excuse my english.

I need to control moving some nodes to trash by it's alias. I have created my custom EventHandler for the "Document.BeforeMoveToTrash" event. I can set the Cancel flag to true, for preventing this action.

Is there any way to set error message in event handlers and show it in backend infobubble? I want to show error with some additional error details.

P.S.: Error bubble in my understanding is:

[image]

Comment: What version of Umbraco?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own speech bubble, but I don't know if it will be overridden by the before save event.

In a custom userControl or method you would be able to use this code to create your own speech bubble.

```
var clientTool = new Umbraco.Web.UI.Pages.ClientTools((System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler);
clientTool.ShowSpeechBubble(SpeechBubbleIcon.Error , "Choose first a content page", "Page has not been added.");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately it not work for me.
In string (System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler throwing "Unable to cast HandlerWrapped to Page" exception.

Comment: and where are you using this code?  in a usercontrol, template, ... ?

Comment: I wrote. I created my custom EventHandler in AppCode

Comment: From which class do you inherit the EventHandler?

Comment: public class EventHandlers : IApplicationEventHandler.
In OnApplicationStarted method I have assigned my control method to event:
Document.BeforeMoveToTrash += Documents_BeforeMove;
Document.BeforeUnPublish += Documents_BeforeMove;

Comment: You should try to use the "ContentService" events instead of the depricated "Document" objects.

Comment: Htllo dampee. I'm sorry for not having answered so long. Thanks for answer. I have changed my code in EventHandler for  ContentService.UnPublishing event. I tried first method which you proposed (SpeechBubble) but it doesn`t work. Then I tried throw exception in handler, but Umbraco can`t handle this exception and show me yellow screen. What I did wrong?

Comment: Code doesn't seem to work in 7.2 for sure. No matter what variation I try of the speech bubble code an error is thrown about casting the handler as a page / basepage.